# Firestore rules : User access to a collection that contain userId

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have 2 collections in my Firestore

users : uid, email
periods : periodId, name, owner_id

I need rules for users access only to it's 'users' collection and another that allow read and write to 'periods' collection only if ownerId uid is equal to authentified user id.

I do that

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write : if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
    
    match /periods/{periodId} {
            allow read, write : if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data. owner_id;
        }
  }

}
```

But it doesn't work.

:(

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you are expecting the users to access `users` collection only when the accessing user is present in the user collection. And then to access `periods` user's owner id should be equal to the owner id available in the 'periods` collection ? 

Am I right ?

Comment: You're right  

Answer (score 2):

You don't share the queries corresponding to these security rules, but we can already identify several problems in your Security rules:

#### 1. For `/users/{userId}` you have some overlapping between `create` and `write`.

The following shall solve this problem:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
}
```

See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure?authuser=0#overlapping_match_statements): "In the case where multiple allow expressions match a request, the access is allowed if any of the conditions is true".

#### 2. For `/periods/{periodId}` you need to split between `read` and `write`.

> For read access rights, the `resource` variable refers to the
> requested document, and `resource.data` is a map of all of the fields
> and values stored in the document.
>
> For write access rights the `request.resource` variable contains the
> future state of the document.

([source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?authuser=0#data_validation))

So the following should do the trick (untested):

```
match /periods/{periodId} {
        allow read : if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner_id;
        allow write : if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.owner_id;
}
```

---

I would suggest you watch the following official [video on Security Rules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw). Actually the entire ["Get to know Cloud Firestore" video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ) is a must...

Comment: @SébastienREMY Hey, did you have time to loo at the proposed answer?

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. in period, user_id is users/PdqJAiVsUDOQfCT5GA3jgOvQZQT2